# Django filter does not exclude results of negative look ahead regex

Tags: python, regex, django, regex-lookarounds

I'm working on a Django app where the database is currently being searched using regular expressions. The returned results seem to be correct, except for when I search with negative look ahead (I would like to be able to exclude some results through filtering with a regex).

For example, the database has a column with many entries of 'None', and I would like to exclude those results when the database is searched. I tried the regex `^(?!None).*$` in an online regex tester, and it passes my tests ('None' strings are not matched, every other string is). However, when the results are returned with Django, the 'None' rows are not excluded. The backend for the DB is SQLite, which according to [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#regex) should allow anything re allows, but I have not had success. Here is the `filter()` call I am using for the regular expression:

```
previousFilters.filter(models.Q(myColumn__regex = r'('+input_expression+')'))
```

Does Django allow the exclusion of results through a negative look ahead in a regular expression?

Comment: Still no luck :(

Comment: I think None is a database fill word meaning the column value for that row is _empty_. Something like `.+` should exclude those nones..

Comment: Note that your regex is supposed to only exclude strings that *start* with `None`, not `'fooNone'`, `' None'`.

Comment: If I remove the `?!` part of the regex, it returns all results that are 'None', so I believe that value in the database is actually a string. But adding the `?!` does not exclude the 'None' values

Comment: Are the values you are trying to exclude null values or the literal string "None"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `^(?:(?!None).)*$` instead since SQLite has no built in regex support and python re module is used.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#regex

```
In [1]: previousFilters.values_list('title', flat=True)
Out[1]: <QuerySet ['Trackk 1', 'Track 2', 'Track 3', 'None']>

In [2]: previousFilters.filter(title__regex=r'^(?:(?!None).)*$').values_list('title', flat=True)
Out[2]: <QuerySet ['Trackk 1', 'Track 2', 'Track 3']>
```

Comment: The string in the database WAS actually 'None', so this worked for me (minus the last `'`). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could add an `exclude` to your query to filter out those results before you perform your search

```
previousFilters.exclude(myColumn='None').filter(models.Q(myColumn__regex = r'('+input_expression+')'))
```

If they are null values you can exclude those like this

```
.exclude(myColumn__isnull=True)
```